# How can I get user_id with access token in laravel passport api?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I am creating mobile application and for login I am using oauth.

For url like `http://localhost/darkhwast/public/oauth/token`
it gives me output json as below:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31536000,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjIyZWQ5YWFjY2U4MDVjYzc4NzUzMWM5NjVkMjdiZDZkNTIwOTQ5NGYxMTllN2Q3YWYyZDQyYWI5MjRjZjYyNTk0ZjhiNTBjNzMyNWMyYjlkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiMjJlZDlhYWNjZTgwNWNjNzg3NTMxYzk2NWQyN2JkNmQ1MjA5NDk0ZjExOWU3ZDdhZjJkNDJhYjkyNGNmNjI1OTRmOGI1MGM3MzI1YzJiOWQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTgxMzQ1MjAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5ODEzNDUyMCwiZXhwIjoxNTI5NjcwNTIwLCJzdWIiOiIzIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbIioiXX0.CdhOhJ_6wb_KphCbnQEwI8iw94MmvlwCnG8PGPSEcm-YoXeaw2WoXiYRizbkhiXIP84BReRVIXxI-Rug6GUWwT1W8cjrvJinQT2UghCcUMqQ6nQlBingKUUlqyaww5rbcIj6RNDVuRtGnVhpSl6g1wsBz534GmNJyaY5F7t9ZJlf4Q80Cay9mV_YcLVnlOTZqTfGaujo6OM24pG6EoCiyOEF-4Vyd4Naov5O_AswuouCT7kuFdMbNYwNu6hB9_swf7yek_-shqgPk3AGJsnkavCI5Mgj3xQdhhtxoy6IxFcebBZ1iI6V_yd0-UDzHHsVZf2bVk4Hx0j84vA4ZkXXDkc85Lxqpafd31i51eXGPaW308VH2EPV9QwNOxNwNF9nl6uAlkcvfhfNBnNx_QGMALmyuNQf1CXY_rkA72pYkekTe4LQGX48dpIJUnFgnj8Jwsfjrda1D6_N5JvrnbvJkVZbCCgOD9vhJUGnVw6PyEcXldWHiW7EJZkAX9XYB571vzN__qkbM--UpU1fMY13HvWe6qTRSPt4NdZudg1zmQOCn0TpvonP4FGGeB_ldEA488LASAAtQdwHQryw4oZvcb1BSDrvw7IVpGva5ky8aIoeQIORPn2Ehg_I1X9q1Yy3UI8iBPQBWgAnGnyoPYhtIvXYNWLUQJaaocLe3eE7osU",
  "refresh_token": "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"
}
```

But how can I get `user_id` in response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OAuth server should have an authenticated API endpoint (using passport), something like `/api/user` or `/api/me`. You use the provided `access_token` to authenticate yourself to retrieve the authenticated user details:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
    ],
]);

$body = (string) $response->getBody();
$remoteUser = json_decode($body);
```

Once you've retrieved the user details, you should have enough to *register* the user account locally within the client app's database (if required).

You *should* encrypt the tokens before storing them on the user record.

Use `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` Laravel's reversible encryption helpers, so it's stored safely but can be decrypted for use later.

Answer (score 1):

I think changing in laravel package would not be good solution.

if we have access_token then we can get user detail by `$request->user()` . Example:

in `api.php` If we write

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user();
});
```

Same like above in any controller if we request API with minimum required headers i.e `Authorization: Bearer access_token` and `Accept : application/json` we can get user detail.

Like in my case(with Header `Authorization: Bearer access_token` and `Accept : application/json`):

```
// with route of middleware: middleware('auth:api')
class UserController extends BaseController
{
  public function index()
      {
        return Auth::user(); // here I got all user detail.        
      }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: how can i get user_id in controllers that client send us Bearer token? please help me

Comment: you can simply write ````echo Auth::user()->id;```` as passport automatically does the trick